# sqoop export to postgresql is ERROR

Tags: postgresql, sqoop

my hive table:

```
create table tmp_base
(
 userid              string
,name                string
,sex                 string
,age                 int
,create_date         TIMESTAMP
)row format delimited
fields terminated by '\t'
stored as textfile
;
```

---

my postgresql table:

```
create table tmp_base
(
 userid              varchar
,name                varchar
,sex                 varchar
,age                 int8
,create_date         TIMESTAMP
)
```

---

my sqoop command:

```
sqoop export \
--connect \
jdbc:postgresql://192.168.20.40:5432/bwarehouse?currentSchema=warehouse \
--username \
gpadmin \
--password \
change \
--table \
tb_user_base_property \
--update-key \
userid \
--columns \
userid,name,sex,age,create_date \
--export-dir \
/$HIVE_WAREHOUSE/db_test.db/tmp_base \
--input-fields-terminated-by \
"\t" \
--input-null-string \
"\\\\N" \
--input-null-non-string \
"\\\\N" \
```

---

the error:

> 2018-06-21 16:26:15,662 FATAL [IPC Server handler 6 on 34454]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Task:
>   attempt_1529372049637_0379_m_000000_0 - exited : java.io.IOException:
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: **ERROR: column "age" is of type
>   bigint but expression is of type character varying**   Hint: You will
>   need to rewrite or cast the expression.   Position: 100   at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.close(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:205)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:676)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:799)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1920)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158) Caused
>   by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "age" is of type
>   bigint but expression is of type character varying   Hint: You will
>   need to rewrite or cast the expression.

**How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: please correct the datatypes in postgresql table use text instead of string , int in place of int8 and time in place of timestamp and try

Comment: @PawanSharma The data type of the field does not have an int ,just hive int2,int4,int8.I used int4,But the error was still reported.The error messege: ERROR: column "age" is of type integer but expression is of type character varying Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression. If the age field is used varchar in postgresql,it's OK.

Comment: @PawanSharma Hello, my database is greenplum, is that a problem?

Comment: sorry no idea about greenplum, check the correct data types you can use in greenplum

Comment: Change all the columns to varchar and see if it is working? I was trying to export data to different schema (not default schema) in Greenplum and facing issues. So your answer will help me too.